# How to set extended properties in SQL Server database projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

Is there any way of setting the MS_Description extended property on objects in the SQL Server Database project in Visual Studio 2013?

Alternatively, is there a way to have extended properties created externally to the project persist in a SQL Server database project and thereby in source control?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You use SQL Doc to document your databases. What dacpac are you talking about? Do you mean that you use a VS Db project to create the database, then somehow update the MS_Description and then use SQL Doc? And your problem is that when you execute the dacpac of VS it overwrites the descriptions that you somehow (how actually?) edited?

Comment: I want to set extended properties in the VS project. Actually SQL Doc is irrelevant for my question, I'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 7):

The SQL table editor consists of a... table above, where you can put your column definitions and the generated SQL code bellow. If you right click on the column headers of the top table, you will see that there are additional hidden columns that you can show. One of them is actuall the Description that you are looking for!

As you can see, it makes use of sp_addextendedproperty stored procedure to update the MS_Description extended property.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do the same for the database and table objects?

Comment: I don't think so. You could add a post-deployment script that does that I suppose.

Comment: You can add the description to the table.  Open the table via the database project in visual studio, then open the properties window.  (commonly F4, otherwise via the menu).  The table properties should be visible, including description.

Comment: To add a description for the table, you can open the table design pane and then right click and select properties. There you can see a description field right below the table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Script to you Project (right-click Project > Add.. > Script (Include In Build) ) and the DAC will take care of the rest.